# How do you use `if` when applying a `raw_input`?

Tags: python

I am somewhat new to Python and coding in general, and I require some help working with `raw_input` and an `if` statement. My code is as follows;

```
    age = raw_input ("How old are you? ")
    if int(raw_input) < 14:
    print "oh yuck"
    if int(raw_input) > 14:
    print "Good, you comprehend things, lets proceed"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issues

There are three issues with your code:

- Python uses indentation for creating blocks.
- You've assigned the input to the variable `age`, so use `age`.
- In Python 3, you have to use `print(...)` instead of `print ...`

### Correct solution

```
age = raw_input("How old are you? ")

if int(age) < 14:
    print("oh yuck")
else:
    print("Good, you comprehend things, lets proceed")
```

Note that this is not equivalent to your code. Your code skips the case `age == 14`. If you want this behaviour, I suggest:

```
age = int(raw_input("How old are you? "))

if age < 14:
    print("oh yuck")
elif age > 14:
    print("Good, you comprehend things, lets proceed")
```

### Learning Python

- http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python - A tutorial that introduces you to programming / Python step by step
- [Manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) - Looking things up and discovering new stuff, e. g. [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) and [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)

Answer (score 0):

```
if int(raw_input) < 14:
```

Should be `int(age)`, and same for the other `if`. `raw_input` is the function you called, but you stored the result from it in the variable `age`. You can't turn a function into an integer.

Rather than converting the age to an integer repeatedly, you could just do it once, when you do the input:

```
age = int(raw_input("How old are you? "))
```

Then you can just do `if age > 14` and so on, since it's already an integer.

I assume the indentation problems (the line following each `if` should be indented at least one space, and preferably four) are just a formatting issue.